# Google Maps, geocoder, javascript: when don't find an address, put marker in the center

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I'm doing a page with geocode, it's working well, but always come in the array of addresses places that it's not catalogated in google maps. Unfortunatly, the geocoder, instead of not doing nothing, put the marker of the not found address in the center of the map.

There's some code to make the geocoder not put this not found marker?

(I'm brazilian, my english it's bad, sorry =))

```
function addMarker(position) {          
        var geocoder;
        geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();  
        geocoder.geocode({'address': address[position]}, function(results, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {              
                places[position] = results[0].geometry.location;
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: places[position],
                    map: mapa,
                    icon: icone, 
                    title: ('OS: ' + arOS[position] + ' - ' + arEndereco[position]), 
                    url: 'OSDETALHES.asp?txtCodigoOS=' + arOS[position]
                });         
                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
                window.open(this.url, '_blank');
                });
            }
            else
            {
                if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OVER_QUERY_LIMIT)
                {
                    setTimeout(function() { addMarker(position); }, (timeout * 3));
                }
            }
            address_position++;
            if (address_position < address.length)
            {
                setTimeout(function() { addMarker(address_position); }, (timeout));
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please show the code that you are using to add markers to the map?

Comment: That's the main function that populate the markers. All I want is: when don't find the address, don't put the marker. It's possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be looking at [Geocoding Results](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding#GeocodingResults) to determine how well Geocoding worked.

**geometry** contains the following information:

**location_type** stores additional data about the specified location. The following values are currently supported:

- **google.maps.GeocoderLocationType.ROOFTOP** indicates that the returned result reflects a precise geocode.
- **google.maps.GeocoderLocationType.RANGE_INTERPOLATED** indicates that the returned result reflects an approximation (usually on a road) interpolated between two precise points (such as intersections). Interpolated results are generally returned when rooftop geocodes are unavailable for a street address.
- **google.maps.GeocoderLocationType.GEOMETRIC_CENTER** indicates that the returned result is the geometric center of a result such as a polyline (for example, a street) or polygon (region).
- **google.maps.GeocoderLocationType.APPROXIMATE** indicates that the returned result is approximate.

Updated Per Comments

I have not used this, but something very close to this should work:

```
if (results[0].geometry.location.location_type != 'ROOFTOP')
{
  // not an exact match
}
```

Comment: Clusterer, in this case, doesn't work. Spiderfier could work, but I can't implementate, it's hard to work in my code.

Answer (score 0):

RANGE_INTERPOLATED, apparently, solved my problem:

```
if (results[0].geometry.location_type == google.maps.GeocoderLocationType.RANGE_INTERPOLATED){
```

Thanks, Erik.